# How to get String after two blank lines in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have string with structure as below

```
This is sentence one.
this is sentence two.

This is sentence three.
This is sentence 4.

This is sentence 5.
This is sentence 6.
```

My requirement is to get the text after two blank lines have been encountered.

I want only this 
    This is sentence 5.
    This is sentence 6.

How do I achieve this in JAVA?

Comment: How have you attempted to solve the problem? Show us your code.

Comment: Main idea is to read file line by line, count empty lines until counter is equal 2. After that next lines are the ones you are looking for. Now please try to code it. Update your question if you will have any problems. Don't forget to include your code attempt and describe problem you are having with it.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it out. will update as soon as I get it.

Comment: Is your multi-line sample really a single String?

Comment: yes I am reading it from a file into a string.

Comment: so they are written already in a file, and you need to get the last 2 lines, correct?

Comment: I need to get everything in a String after two empty lines are encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n[\\r\\n]+");
String[] result = p.split(str);

 for(int i=2;i<result.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
```

The below solution also works well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple and ugly way to do it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    String empty = "";
    int counter = 0;


    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String temp = in.nextLine();
        if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(empty)) {
            counter++;
            if (counter == 2) {
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks to user mbroshi for pointing out my old code is flawed

Comment: This will not work.  Presumably, the `goal` sentence is not known until run time.  OP wants lines after two blanks.

Comment: Yeah this solution won't work because the requirements is to get the substring after two blank lines have been encountered.

Comment: just changed the code to reflect that. thanks for the heads up